# R dplyr 0.7.2 - functional programming. Resolving dataframe name

Tags: r, function

I am writing a R function using dplyr 0.7.2 syntax to pass input and output data frame names and a column name to sort on. The following is the code I have.

```
#test data frame creation

lb<- data.frame(study  = replicate(25,"ABC"),  
            subjid = c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"),
            visit  = c("SCREENING","VISIT1","VISIT2","VISIT3","EOT"),
            visitn = c(-1,1,2,3,4),
            param  = c("ALB","AST","HGB","HCT","LDL"),
            aval   = replicate(5, sample(c(20:100), 1, rep = TRUE)))

#sort function- user to provide input/output df names and column name to sort on

 sortdf <- function(ind,outd,col){

  col <- enquo(col)

  outd <- ind  %>% arrange(!!col)

  outd <<- outd # return  dataframe to workspace

}

sortdf(lb,lb_sort, visitn)
```

the above code works but the output df name  is not getting resolved to lb_sort. output df is named as the name of the associated parameter (outd).  Need some help!

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make use of the `<<` in this context. In effect, your function is a wrapper for `arrange`:

```
  my_sort <- function(df, col) {
        col <- enquo(col)
        df %>% 
            arrange(!!col)
    }

    my_sort(df = lb, col = visitn)
```

Then you could create your objects as usual:

```
my_sort(df = lb, col = visitn) -> sorted_stuff
```

## Edit

As per request, forcing creation of names object in parent environment.

```
my_sort <- function(df, col, some_name) {
    col <- enquo(col)
    df %>%
        arrange(!!col) -> dta_a


    # Gather env. inf
    e <- environment() # current environment
    p <- parent.env(e)

    # Create object in parent env.
    assign(x = some_name,
           value = dta_a,
           envir = p)

    # If desired return another object
    # return(some_other_data)
}

my_sort(df = lb, col = visitn, some_name ="created_data")
```

### Explanation

- **`e`**/**`p`** objects are used to gather information about functions current and parent environment
- **`assign`** uses string and creates names object in function's parent environment. Global environment, if called as provided in the example.

### Remarks

This is odd behaviour, when called as shown:

```
>> ls()
[1] "lb"      "my_sort"
>> my_sort(df = lb, col = visitn, some_name ="created_data")
>> ls()
[1] "created_data" "lb"           "my_sort"
```

The function leaves `"created_data"` object in global environment. This is inconsistent with expected behaviour where the user would usually create objects:

```
my_sort(df = lb, col = visitn) -> created_data
```

and I wouldn't encourage using it. If the actual problem is concerned with returning multiple objects a potentially better approach may involve packing all the results into a list and returning one list:

```
list(result_1 = mtcars,
     result_2 = airquality)
```

Comment: Konrad, Thanks for your reply!  Your solution works. Just out of curiosity, I am interested to know if we can create intermediate dfs with in the function by passing the df names in the function call . Is this possible?